# How to rename multiple fastq files using for loop

Tags: bash

I have several files like this:

```
sub_TK273759_R1.fastq
sub_TK273759_R2.fastq
sub_TK273763_R1.fastq
sub_TK273763_R2.fastq
sub_TK273766_R1.fastq
sub_TK273766_R1.fastq
```

How can I rename all files like this:

```
TK273759_R1.fastq
TK273759_R2.fastq
TK273763_R1.fastq
TK273763_R2.fastq
TK273766_R1.fastq
TK273766_R2.fastq
```

Comment: Does it have to be done with a `for` loop? Also, can you confirm that you just want to remove the initial `sub_` prefix from each name? How should potential name clashes be handled (if a name already exists without `sub_`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of `rename`. Depending on which one you have, one of these will work for you:

```
rename sub_ '' sub_*        # rename -V -> "rename from util-linux 2.33.1"
rename 's/^sub_//' sub_*    # rename -V -> "Unknown option: V"
```

These two will object if the target filename already exists.

Alternatively you can use a loop, but it's far less efficient:

```
for f in sub_*
do
    mv "$f" "${f#sub_}"
done
```

This will silently overwrite the target filename if it already exists